# CultureInfo does not work in release mode properly

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am facing some genuine issue with my Xamarin Android Mobile Application.

I have code, which is working fine in Debug mode but not working in Release mode. Of course, in Release mode I am using Link SDK assemblies..

Here is the piece of code

```
return date.ToString(outputFormat, new CultureInfo("ar-SA").DateTimeFormat);
```

It works in Debug mode but in Release mode gives exception saying **not a valid calendar for the given culture**

Comment: Same problem [as this bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31228).  If an update doesn't fix it then file a bug report for Arabic.

Comment: Reference the calendar directly in code so the static analysis of the `Linker` sees that it is in use: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59077#c5

Comment: @SushiHangover Calendar Class I can refer in code, but how to refer Calendar with specific culture. Locale goes as string parameter to calendar, I think it uses reflection to find that locale.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hard reference to the locale/culture that you are using and just dispose of it after.

Example:

```
using (var locale = new Java.Util.Locale("ar-SA"))
{
   // Do nothing: A non-reflection reference for the Linker
}
```

Note: There are bugzilla references to do this, but I do not have those links, search bugzilla.xamarin.com for more details.